# duplicated animation after update to Android Jelly Beans

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using JQuery 1.1.0 and Phonegap 1.9.0 to develop a html5 App for Android. I have a little animation which draws a battery on the canvas and updates it. It looks like a battery, which is loading. It worked very well on android 4.0.4.

Yesterday I received the update to Android 4.1.1 on my Galaxy Nexus. After that change I had issues with my animation. Now it draws to images on the canvas, one is in front and the other is behind with wrong coordinates. I think it has something to do with the Changes to Java Script Engine V8, maybe caching issues?! On every browser on my PC the animation works very well.

My html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title>Hella App</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css"/>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>

<style>
    .ui-page { background: black;}
</style>

</head>

   <body>

<div data-role="page" id="dataPageBattery" data-theme="a">
    <h2 align="center">Battery State</h2>
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
        <h1>Car Data</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" align="center">
        <canvas id="myBatteryCanvas" width="device-width"
            height="device-height">                        
            Sorry, your browser doesn't support canvas technology        
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <h4 align="center" id="batteryProzent"></h4>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="battery.js"></script>
    <script>$(document).on("pageshow",init());</script> 


    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="persFooter">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.html" data-icon="home">Connect</a></li>
                <li><a href="carView.html" data-icon="gear">Cars</a></li>
                <li><a href="infoView.html" data-icon="info">Info</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>                                       
$('#dataPageBattery').on('swipeleft',function(){ 
 $.mobile.changePage("geolocation.html", { transition: "slide"});   
 console.log('slideLeft');
})  

$('#dataPageBattery').on('swiperight',function(){ 
 $.mobile.changePage("fuelGauge.html", { transition: "slide", reverse: 'true'});    
 console.log('slideLeft');
})  
     </script>
</div>



    </body>
    </html>
```

My java script code, which I'm loading:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myBatteryCanvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var x = 50;
      var y = canvas.height - 30;
      var mx = 2;
      var my = 1;
      var WIDTH = canvas.width;
      var HEIGHT = canvas.height;
     var prozent = 1;

  function drawRect(y, farbe) {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(124, y, 50, 21);
ctx.fillStyle = farbe;
ctx.fill();

window.setTimeout("draw()", 10);
 }

 function draw() {
if (y >= 80) {
    y -= my;
    window.setTimeout("drawRect(y,'red')", 10);
} else if (y >= 50) {
    y -= my;
    window.setTimeout("drawRect(y,'orange')", 10);
    ctx.rect(124, 50 + 50, 50, 40);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
    ctx.fill();

} else {
    ctx.rect(124, 50, 50, canvas.height - 60);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'lightgreen';
    ctx.fill();
}

document.getElementById('batteryProzent').innerHTML = '> ' + prozent + ' %';
prozent++;
if (prozent % 4 == 0)
    prozent++;
 }

 function init() {
ctx.rect(122, 40, 54, 100);
ctx.fillStyle = 'floralwhite';
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth = 4;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#303030';
ctx.stroke();

draw();
 }
```

Another nice issue: If I use this html page as the first page to start with inside the Phonegap code, there is no problem. But if I use it inside the whole App, I'm facing the problems.
For this reason, I post my first page too:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title> BLE App</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="Logo.png" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css"/>
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

<style>
    .ui-page { background: black;}
</style>

</head> 
  <body> 

 <div data-role="page" id="mainPage" data-theme="a"> 
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
    <h1> BLE</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
    <!-- <p> BLE Test App</p> -->
    <label for="mainPage_textFrage">Find BLE Devices:</label>
    <!-- <input type="text" id="mainPage_textFrage" value="" placeholder="Ihre Frage"/> -->
    <a data-role=button id="mainPage_showAnswerButton">Search</a>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="persFooter">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html" data-icon="home">Connect</a></li>
            <li><a href="carView.html" data-icon="gear">Cars</a></li>
            <li><a href="infoView.html" data-icon="info">Info</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /footer -->
  </div>

   <script>                                    
$('#mainPage_showAnswerButton').on('click',function(){
 $.mobile.changePage("searchResult.html", { transition: "slideup"});
 console.log('click');
})                                       
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Is there somebody with same issues? Can somebody help?

Thanks so far!

UPDATE:
I updated JQuery to 1.7.2 and JQuery Mobile to 1.1.1. But still there is no change. The animation isn't working.

Comment: There is more strange stuff going on. If I try to erase the canvas after the animation with: ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); Only one battery disappears. The other is still there, but I cleared the whole canvas. And again: Everything is fine, if I start this page with Phonegap first. Any ideas?

Comment: UPDATE: If I start the page first, there are no problems. But if i insert an alert('here') tag to see how often it is called. The problem is there same. The image is duplicated. It looks like the problem is time critical. But I don't know how to fix it!

Answer (score 5):

Possible solution:

Removing the following line from jquery-mobile-css eliminates the problem:

```
/*content area*/
.ui-content { border-width: 0; overflow: visible; overflow-x: hidden; padding: 15px; }
```

(removing "overflow-x: hidden" is sufficient).

A better solution is to override the "overflow-x" attribute on the surrounding div-element (not the canvas-element itself).

Example (for battery-status):

```
<div data-role="content" align="center" data-theme="a" style="overflow-x: visible">
 <canvas id="myBatteryCanvas" width="device-width" height="device-height">                        
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support canvas technology        
 </canvas>
</div>
```

See also http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35474

Answer (score 0):

When things go wrong when you transition from one page to another but not when you load the page itself standalone, it sounds like you need to (un)load stuff during the page transitions. jQuery Mobile loads anything inside `<div data-role="page">...</div>` on a page transition. That also means that anything outside these divs is ignored. Not only that, but the javascript code from the previous page still continues on to the next.

I see the two blocks of `<script>...</script>` at the bottom of the 2 HTML pages and only one of those will load, namely the one on the page that you refresh at. Make sure these scripts are loaded by inserting the the scripts inside the `data-role="page` divs

You should change the following

```
<script>$(document).ready(window.setTimeout("init()", 500));</script>
```

to

```
<script>$(document).on("pageshow",window.setTimeout("init()", 500));</script>
```

per the [jQM documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) you shouldn't use `$(document).ready(...)`

Comment: First: You solved my swipe problem. It works now. Thanks a lot. But the problem with the duplicate battery animation ist still the same. I red the documentation you mentioned and you are right. So I changed my code to script>$(document).ready(onDeviceReadyFuel());</script> But the problem is this the same. The screen shows 2 animations and the are running synchron. Really strange. If i open the files on my PC with IE9, everything is fine. Ideas?

Comment: UPDATE: I have another animation it works with images. One as a background image another moving on top of that. It should look like a fuel Gauge in a car. There is the same problem. The animation shows two pointers, not only one. And the are both moving. If I swipe back and again to the animation one is fixed and the other is moving. Maybe these problems have to do with caching?

Comment: Yes, because you bind `init()` each time the page loads to the `$(document).on("pageshow",...)`. So when you reopen the page, you bind again and two `init()`'s start. Could you update your code above so that it reflects your changes?

Comment: I updated the first 2 files the last is the same! Do have any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: Somebody how can give me a hint with my problem?

Comment: So to make things clear: You open the homepage and when you go to the fuelGauge.html page by swiping right ('swiperight'), you see the background with 2 moving pointers? Try to find out what functions are running twice.

Comment: not only swipe! i have buttons: reaction is the same! There are no functions called twice, as far as a can tell. I put alert inside the .js code! nothing twice! Is there a way to put something like a flag inside the could, that it isn't possible to call it twice?

Comment: Any suggestions about the flag topic?

Comment: Is there someone, who has the same issues after updating to android 4.1?

Comment: While porting my application to iPhone with phonegap I noticed some strange behaviour. It seems that I ignored [this phonegap event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#deviceready), when I run the code only after phonegap is ready, then the application behaves normally.

Comment: Also, when you say that your code isn't running twice then it has no use to prevent it from running twice...

Comment: I changed the code and added the phonegap function. But it's still the same problem. It not clear to me why I should change my could if it's running perfect with android 4.0, but not with 4.1. I'm not seeing the problems! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same issue here with our phone running Android 4.1.1. We have an html5 canvas application that displays a slider. The image of the slider is displayed 2 times. On our android 4.1, 4.0, 2.3 devices it displays fine. I don't think you can workaround this defect with a simple java script change. It is simply broken in the latest Jellybean patch.

We've used Nexus S and Galaxy Nexus phones with multiple different versions of android to prove this out (it's not phone specific).